# Problem with NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I can't understand why this isn't working.

```
   NSDateFormatter * dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM YYYY"];
   NSDate * complDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"27 June 2011"];
```

`complDate` returns `2010-12-25 21:00:00 +0000`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use lowercase "y" for your format string:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];
```

Uppercase "Y" indicates "Week of Year". See the [Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW4); it contains a link to the Unicode format specifiers that `NSDateFormatter` uses.

Comment: NSDateFormatter * dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d MMMM yyyy"];
 NSDate * complDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"27 June 2011"];
result is 2011-06-26 20:00:00 +0000

Comment: That's caused by the time zone; I believe that the date formatter assumes you want the result in GMT by default. Use `setTimeZone:` to make it use your system's time zone value.

Comment: Set time zone to [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"MSK"]]; doesn't help
But something magic:
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM d"];
 NSString * dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:complDate]; 
 [dateFormat release];

Gives me correct Date

Answer (score 0):

`setDateFromat:` function used for formatting sting object for `stringFromDate:` function. `dateFromString:` returns `NSDate` object.

Example from Docs:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm"];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:162000];

NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"formattedDateString: %@", formattedDateString);
// For US English, the output may be:
// formattedDateString: 2001-01-02 at 13:00
```